# How to modify original DateTime object without change its value?

Tags: php, datetime

I'm trying to get the current date/time using OOP way as follow:

```
$now = new \DateTime(); // 2015-05-24 11:21:36 -> this works fine
```

and also I'm adding 1 week to the same object `$now` so I did this:

```
$expireTime = $now->modify('+1 week'); // 2015-05-31 11:21:36 -> this also works fine
```

In the same method if I do this:

```
echo $now; 
// Output: 2015-05-31 11:28:59
// Got wrong value, should be original date without modification

echo $expireTime;
// Output: 2015-05-31 11:28:59 
// Got the right value since I have added 1 week
```

Why? How do I add a week without modify the original object?

**EDIT:** I have found the solution by cloning the original object and modifying the cloned one but I want to know if this behavior is right and why

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are probably looking for the [`DateTimeImmutable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php) class, which is the same, but it doesn't change the original value. As from the manual:

> This class behaves the same as DateTime **except it never modifies itself** but returns a new object instead.